# Bash getting stuck when printing special character

Tags: terminal, growl, iterm

I have this function in my .profile, which creates a growl notification using iTerm2:

```
function growl()
{
    echo -n -e $'\e]9;'"$@"'\007'
}
```

But, if I do `declare -f growl`, Bash will become stuck and your only option is to close the current terminal window.

Output in iTerm2 + getting stucked:

```
growl () 
{ 
    echo -n -e '
```

Output in Terminal + bell:

```
growl () 
{ 
    echo -n -e '

7;file://path/to/current/work/dir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declare -f growl`, as you probably know, is printing the complete definition of the function, including the control characters.

I suggest changing the definition so it prints the characters you want without having to have them literally included in the function definition.  Bash's `echo` command takes a `-e` option that enables it to recognize escape sequences such as `\a` for the bell character.  `info bash` and search for "echo" for more information.

(If you're asking how to recover once you've messed up your terminal emulator, I don't have an answer.)

EDIT: I misread the question.  The problem is that you're using the `$'...'` syntax, which expands escape sequences to actual control characters.  Apparently `declare -f` is printing the expanded strings.  Just don't use the `$'...'` syntax.

```
function growl()
{
    echo -n -e '\e]9;'"$@"'\a'
}
```

(`'\a'` is equivalent to `'\007'`.)

EDIT2: Fixed typo

EDIT3: Apparently in some versions of bash, `echo -n -e '\e'` doesn't print an escape character, but '\033' does work.  Revised solution:

```
function growl()
{
    echo -n -e '\033]9;'"$@"'\a'
}
```

(The questioner is using bash 3.2.48.  I've confirmed that 3.2.25 does this correctly.  It's odd.)

Comment: What is the equivalent of \e]9;

Comment: Invalid syntax + `echo -n -e $\e]9;'"$@"'\a'` doesn't display the growl notification

Comment: @Tyilo: Sorry, I deleted the wrong character.  I just update it; try again.  (BTW, `Growl` is apparently a MacOS-specific thing, so I can't actually test it.)

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  When I copy-and-paste your original definition into my bash shell, then run `growl | od -c`, I get "033   ]   9   ;  \a".  When I copy-and-paste my own updated) definition and run the same command, I get the same output -- and after that, `declare -f growl` doesn't display any non-printable characters.  How exactly does it not work?

Comment: The function doesn't display the growl notification in iTerm2

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure how helpful I can be with that.  Did it solve the problem with `declare -f growl` freezing your terminal?  [This web page](http://aming-blog.blogspot.com/2011/01/growl-notification-from-iterm-2.html) says you need to enable notifications in Preferences; have you done that?

Answer (score 1):

Final solution:

Wrap it inside single-quotes and use eval:

```
function growl()
{
    eval 'echo -e -n $'"'"'\e]9;'"'"'"$@"'"'"'\007'"'"';'
}
```

Comment: That's odd.  All three solutions (the one in your question, the one in my answer, and the one in your final solution) *should* work identically. the only difference being the behavior of `declare -f growl` (I just verified this with bash 4.2.8).  Can you try something for me?  Copy-and-paste each of the three definitions, then run `growl hello | od -c`.  I get exactly the same output for each version.  If you do, I wonder why not all the versions are working for you; if you don't, something else strange is going on.

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere.  It looks like your bash's built-in `echo -e` doesn't recognize `'\e'`.  Does `echo -e -n '\e' | od -c' show a backslash followed by an 'e'?  It *should* show "033", an escape character.  What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` show?  What happens if you change the `\e` in my solution to '\033`?

Comment: Cool.  (And you might consider using printf rather than echo, since its behavior is more stable; future versions of bash could break your function.)  BTW, I just built bash-3.2.48 on Ubuntu, and it handles `\e` correctly.  Curiouser and curiouser.